# Exclude db in simple recovery mode from t-log backup

Tags: sql-server

We have a T-log Maintenance plan for few databases. One of the database "ABC" in simple recovery mode. Our maintenance plan fails with the error "Database ABC will not be backed up because it does not have recovery mode set to full or bulk"

Please help me fix this issue without changing ABC database to full recovery mode

Version: SQL Server 2005 standard edition SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i resolved the issue on my own.... I excluded this db from MP by changing the db to full-recovery mode .....I cant believe i wasted 3 hours on this :(

Comment: But didn't you say in the original statement of the problem: "Please help me fix this issue without changing ABC database to full recovery mode"? If there was a legitimate reason for this database to be in simple recover, changing it to full recovery just so your maintenance plan would work seems like overkill.

Comment: @Ben Thul I changed the recovery to full, excluded from MP and changed it to Simple again :) I forgot to mention it in my previous comment. Thanks for the concern!